# How to send JSON payload as body in POST in AFMotion

Tags: ruby, afnetworking, mime, rubymotion

AFMotion says

> The request_parameters is a hash containing your parameters to attach
>   as the request body or URL parameters, depending on request type.

However, I can't figure out how to send a `JSON` request as a `Body` payload.

```
client.post("users", name: "@clayallsopp", library: "AFMotion") do |result|
  ...
end
```

This example from their page sends `Content-Type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8`, however, my api requires the MIME type to be `application/json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `request_serializer` and `response_serializer` both to `:json` to properly send/receive JSON:

```
@client = AFMotion::Client.build("https://alpha-api.app.net/") do
  request_serializer :json
  response_serializer :json
end
```

AFNetworking will then use the `AFJSONRequestSerializer` which will set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`.